# Regular Expression Should not start with a character and contain a sequence

Tags: regex

For example, should not start with **h** and should contain **ap**.
Should match **ap**ology, r**ap** god, tr**ap** but not match h**ap**py.

I tried

```
^[^h](ap)*
```

but it doesn't match sequences which start with `ap` like *ap*ology.

Comment: Try `^(?!h).*ap`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pcznct/1)

Comment: I posted solutions that match the whole string or just whole words, see [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52555784/3832970). Please let know which one works for you so that I could explain how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!h).*ap
```

See the [following demo](https://regex101.com/r/pcznct/1). To match the whole string to the end, append `.*` at the end:

```
^(?!h).*ap.*
```

If you plan to only match words following the rules you outlined, you may use

```
\b(?!h)\w*ap\w*
```

Or, without a lookahead:

```
\b([^\Wh]\w*)?ap\w*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pcznct/2) and the [demo without a lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/pcznct/3).

Answer (score 0):

@WiktorStribiżew's comment with negative lookahead is correct (you might want to add `.*` to it if you want to match the whole string).

For completeness, you can also use alternation:

```
^(?:[^h].*ap|ap).*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ecVTGm/1